# Delete Values for Hidden DIVs

Tags: jquery

I have hidden DIVS that show form elements dependent on what radio button is clicked. I see many ways of doing this, and I implemented one of them, and it does work. The problem is if someone changes their mind and clicks one radio button, and then a different one. Whatever was filled out in the DIV associated with their first clicked button is now hidden, but the value is still there and gets submitted with the form. I need a way to empty-out/delete the form element values they originally filled out if someone ends up clicking a different radio button..

I tried adding this line to my working code, but it did not seem to do anything:

```
$("#dvCanDentalDate, #dvCanDentalDep, #dvDHMO").val('')
```

Here's the complete block of script. Except for the line of code above that I added in 2 places, the rest works just fine.

```
$('input[name=dental]').click(function () {
    if (this.id == "dental1") {
        $("#dvChooseDental").show('slow');
        $("#dvDentalWaive, #dvCanDentalDate, #dvCanDentalDep, #dvDHMO").hide('slow');
    } else if (this.id == "dental2") {
        $("#dvDentalWaive").show('slow');
        $("#dvChooseDental, #dvCanDentalDate, #dvCanDentalDep, #dvDHMO").hide('slow');
        $("#dvCanDentalDate, #dvCanDentalDep, #dvDHMO").val('')
    } else if (this.id == "dental3") {
        $("#dvDentalWaive").show('slow');
        $("#dvChooseDental, #dvCanDentalDate, #dvCanDentalDep, #dvDHMO").hide('slow');
        $("#dvCanDentalDate, #dvCanDentalDep, #dvDHMO").val('')
    } else if (this.id == "dental4") {
        $("#dvCanDentalDate, #dvDentalWaive").show('slow');
        $("#dvChooseDental, #dvCanDentalDep, #dvDHMO").hide('slow');
    } else if (this.id == "dental5") {
        $("#dvCanDentalDate, #dvCanDentalDep, #dvDentalWaive").show('slow');
        $("#dvChooseDental, #dvDHMO").hide('slow');     
    } else {
        $("#dvChooseDental, #dvCanDentalDate, #dvCanDentalDep, #dvDentalWaive, #dvDHMO").hide('slow');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.html('')` to empty divs

`$("#dvCanDentalDate, #dvCanDentalDep, #dvDHMO").html('')`

or

`$("#dvCanDentalDate, #dvCanDentalDep, #dvDHMO").empty()`

Comment: To elaborate: `input` elements have `value`s (some exceptions), but `div` and other markup tags do not have `value`s

Comment: `.empty` is probably a safer solution re: event handlers etc.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, besides the fine solution from @Krishna, would be to disable the elements; disabled form elements are not submitted with the form. So, something like:

```
$("#dvChooseDental").show('slow').find(':input').prop('disabled', false);
$("#dvDentalWaive, #dvCanDentalDate, #dvCanDentalDep, #dvDHMO").hide('slow').find(':input').prop('disabled', true);
```

This would have the additional benefit of not having to recreate your HTML after having emptied it previously.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried the answer from @Krishna yet, but I have tried Mike's. I have to make this as "bulletproof" as possible. Here's what happened. I fill in the content associated with the first radio button. Then, I select another, which disables the first response. However, if I am so scatter-brained that I then want to go back to my first response, or any other radio button, it's still disabled. Maybe this is overkill, but how would I toggle the "disabled" off again if someone ends up clicking a third or more times?